# Зависает программа без ошибки

Tags: ассемблер

Компилятор: FASM
Опции ассемблера: `$SOURCE$ $PROGRAM.OBJ$ -s $LSTOUTPUT$`
Опции компоновщика: `$PROGRAM.OBJ$ $MACRO.OBJ$ -g -o $PROGRAM$ -m32`

```
format ELF

section '.text' executable
public _main
_main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    ret
```

Данный кусок кода, зависает. Хотя тут ничего толком не происходит. Если убрать push ebp - все будет хорошо. Почему оно так?

Comment: Адрес возврата - в стеке. Вы пихаете в стек ещё одно значение... куда, спрашивается, будет выполнен возврат?

Comment: Программа *без ошибки* не зависает :)

Comment: Инструкция `RET` осуществляет переход по адресу, который вы за`PUSH`или в стек. Возьмите за правило - если есть `push`, то обязательно должен быть `pop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в процедуре есть пролог

```
push    ebp            ;сохраняем базу предыдущего фрейма
mov     ebp,esp        ;записываем базу нового фрейма
sub     esp,vars_size  ;резервируем фрейм локальных переменных (если они есть)
```

то, соответственно, должен быть и эпилог

```
mov     esp,ebp        ;возвращяем указатель стека к сохранённой старой базе
pop     ebp            ;восстанавливаем старую базу
```

Если у вас EBP/ESP не меняются (например, когда нет локальных переменных и переданных параметров), то и пролог/эпилог не нужен. В процедуре, которая ничего не делает достаточно всего лишь одной инструкции - `ret`.

Comment: Спасибо больше, помогло)